# making automated generate closing when using backtick

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions, backticks

hi im currently wanted to ask is there an extension which help auto generate closing when i coding inside the backtick cuz whenever i code like javascript and i put like `document.writeln(<p>text</p>`) the `<p>` when i make as an paragraph it doesn't generate `</p>` which mean i have to type again manually the closing of `</p>` , is there an extension to make it happen like auto generate even inside of  backtick ? search at google but didnt give me any of result instead they recommending extension for vscode starter which make me more confused. please anyone can Help Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this extension [Auto Close Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag) for your VSCode.

Comment: ok i will try and i will Reply again if its working thank you

Comment: its not working :v it doesnt automatically add that thing after i type `<p>` inside the backtick :v